# Properties as indexed map in gae-datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a little but important doubt about Low-Level Datastore from Google App Engine.
I need a document structure like this :

```
{infNfe id="1234"
    det={nItem="1",prod="prodname"},
    det={nItem="2",prod="prodname"},
    det={nItem="3",prod="prodname"}
}
```

Note that **det** element is a Map too, but unfortunately datastore do not accept Map as *indexed* property.

Locking some example, I found something like it:

```
Entity i = new Entity("infNfe","key");
i.setProperty("id",1234);
Entity det1 = new Entity("det",i.getKey());
det1.setProperty("nItem",1);
det1.setProperty("prod","prodname");
..Others dests..
```

But, when I query some child entity, I get incomplete references.

```
Query dq= new Query("det");
dq.setAncestor(i.getKey());
..Printing result..
{nItem="1",prod="prodname"}
```

By this approach I can only get one **det** entity at a time.
How can I get the parent and children at once ?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the child method is that you end up with lots of entities, which means more cost because you pay per get/put/query result (at least under the new pricing).

Objectify is a great framework for doing these queries. To do a map using Objectify, you create a second class with the two types you want to map:

```
class Det
{
    long nItem;
    String prod;
}

class InfNfe
{
    @Id Long id;
    @Embedded List<Det> dets;
}
```

It will then store data like the following

```
id = 1
dets.nItem = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dets.prod = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

with Objectify, you can then specify which items are indexed and you can query based on some of this data (although I don't know off hand how it manages to query data in the middle of an array).